# Static Queue vs Shared Preferences

Tags: android, static, sharedpreferences

I have an app with breadcrumb style navigation. Each level has its own data (like, name, id ect).

I currently have a custom activity that extends the android activity which takes care of the navigation aspect. It uses a sort of queue containing each level along with the data mentioned above. This queue is static (within the custom activity class) and used to determine which level a user is on and provide data for all levels below it.

Is this bad practice? Should I be using shared preferences instead?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you post the code relevant to the queue? It'll easier to tell if `SharedPreferences` would be better that way.

Comment: Instead of having a global queue, why not pass the relevant level data to each activity through a Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So the scope of your Static Queue will be, the scope of your application in memory space. And `SharedPreference` will be available till the scope of Application on device (till user un-install from device).

So may be there is possibilities if your application no longer running then you can loss your navigation track. But if its available in `SharedPreference` then you can restore the state of your application at any time.

Comment: It's okay in this instance that the Queue goes out of scope with the memory as the security of the app requires a pin when the user returns and restarts at the root of the navigation tree either way. Functionality-wise, it fits my purpose perfectly.

My main concern is whether or not this is bad practice. I couldn't find many resources when it comes to static guidelines when shared between activities.

Comment: Then you are fine, if its suitable for your purpose, SharedPreference just live with your application life scope and yupp in lite weight form of data.